# Are chaotic systems computable in polynomial time

Tags: time-complexity, polynomial-time

Suppose the parameters/inputs of the computation include the time at which the configuration of a particular deterministic chaotic system needs to be computed.

Say, for instance, as input we have a start configuration of the chaotic [Rule 30](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_30) cellular automata and a time-step $t$, and as output, we require the configuration at time-step $t$.

What can be said about the computational complexity of such a computation?

Comment: See Problem 3 at https://blog.wolfram.com/2019/10/01/announcing-the-rule-30-prizes/

Comment: Thank you! This is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Wolfram's rule 30 is a one dimensional cellular automaton.
If you want to know the state of the *CA* at step $t$, given the initial configuration, you just need to run the rule for $t$ steps. At every step the computation consist in no more than a bunch of *if*'s, so the time complexity of such  *CA* is linear in $t$.

Comment: Ahhh yes of course, can we do better?

Comment: @pkwssis  I strongly doubt it, but I don't know if anyone ever prooved it formally. If you want to expand your knowledge on cellular automatons, I strongly recommend that you read the book "A New Kind of Science" written by Wolfram himself.

Comment: This answer is not quite right; the running time is actually quadratic in $t$, as explained in the link in my comment above.  The reason is that you need to simulate up to $t$ cells.  Thus, simulating a single step takes $O(t)$ time, not $O(1)$ time.  Multiply that by $t$ steps, and you get $O(t^2)$ time.  As explained in the link I provided, it is an open question whether we can do substantially better.